# Will negative bases with irrational exponents get a real or imaginary number?

Tags: exponentiation, irrational-numbers

Here are a few examples:

$$(-1)^{\sqrt{2}},(-2)^{\pi},(-3)^{e}$$

From what I've learned, negative bases must have denominators of the exponent odd.

Normally if we do $(-2)^{0.258}$ it would be the same as $(-2)^{50/129}$. That means that since $129$ is odd, it will give a real number.

But for irrational numbers I'm not sure if we can determine if it's going to be odd on the denominator or not because you can't convert it to a fraction.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296193/exponentiation-when-the-exponent-is-irrational?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Express the numbers as such $$-1=e^{i\pi},\quad-2=2\cdot e^{i\pi}$$
and see if you can go from there.

By the way, it is not true that if the denominator is odd, the result will be real for you must bear in mind that there are always complex roots lurking in the background.

E.g. $\sqrt[3]{1}= 1, e^{\frac{i2\pi}{3}},e^{\frac{i4\pi}{3}}$

Comment: So the formula is `-b = b*e^(i*pi)`?

Comment: @puretppc yup!!

Answer (score 0):

Again, let us use Euler's identity. If $e$ is the base of the natural logarith, and $i*2=-1$, then:

$$e^{i}+1=0$$

We can conclude that for all integers $z$:

$$\ln(-1)=i(2z+1)

and thus:

$$\ln(-r)=\ln(r)+i(2z+1)$$

Now, let $n$ be an irrational number and $H$ be the arc measure of a half-circle (180 degrees,  radians, 200 grads, 2 quadrants, etc)

Applying a generalized version of Euler's formula:

$$(-r)^n=(e^{ln(-r)+i2πz})^n=(e^{ln(r)+iπ+i2πz})^n=(e^{ln(r)+iπ(2z+1)})^n=e^{nln(r)+iπn(2z+1)}=r^n\cos(Hn(2z+1)+ir^n\sin(Hn(2z+1)$$

Now, the zeroes of the sine function are integer multiples of a half-circle. $n$ being irrational and $2z+1$ being rational and always nonzero ($2z+1=0$ has no Diophantine solution), their product is irrational and the sine is always nonzero for all integers $z$, so the imaginary part can not vanish.

(fun fact: at least one of $r$, $n$, or $(-r)^n$ must be transcendental, per Gelfond-Schneider theorem)